# NGINX : HTTP/2 not used for CSS / JS ressources

Tags: nginx

I have enabled HTTP/2 support on my NGINX server with this config :

```
# WWW DOMAIN
# -----------------------------
server {
    # PORT
    # -------------------------
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    # SERVER NAME
    # -------------------------
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
```

Now when I make an HTTP/2 test, my site is indicated as "HTTP/2 Supported".

The problem is when I make a check (with google developer tool for example), I can see that CSS & JS files are not loaded with HTTP/2 but still with HTTP/1.1 protocol. It's strange because ressources are not defined on sub domains. We access it for example by mydomain.com/css/myfile.css

The only specificity in my NGINX conf about CSS & JS files is :

```
# JS & CSS
# -------------------------
location ~* .(css|js)$ {
    expires 7d;
}
```

Do you have an idea of which element in my config cans block JS & CSS HTTP/2 delivery ?

Comment: Just to clarify, are your css/js resources being served from the exact same domain as html? You are not using a CDN or anything, right?

Comment: No I don't use CDN and CSS/JS files are served by the same domain (not by a sub-domain). Ressources are just defined in sub-folder : www.mydomain.com/css/

Comment: Could it be that your css/js files are cached? So the browser has no need to download them again and still shows them with the  HTTP/1.1 protocol. Just clear your cache.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden That's exactly what was the problem for me. I was using serivce workers and the cached files were being shown as transferred through HTTP1.1. Once I checked the "bypass for network" flag in the dev tools menu, they were shown as being downloaded with HTTP2. Cheers!